# Datagridview and properties to Contained Objects

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-2.0

I have a BindingList of objects. The objects contain public properties to be displayed by a databindingview. Unfortunately I can't get the properties that return field data of contained objects to work. Take for instance the contrived example below:

```
Public Class ChimpDiet
{
  public string favoritefood;
}


Public Class Chimpanzee
{
  private ChimpDiet diet;

  [DisplayName("Chimp's favorite food")]
  public string favoritefood
  { get { return diet.favoritefood; } }

  [DisplayName("Chimp's nickname")]
  public string nickname { get; set; }

  public Chimpanzee()
  {
    diet = new ChimpDiet();
  } 
}
```

When I set a BindingList of Chimpanzees as the datasource of the datagridview, the property favoritefood causes errors to pop up:

*The following exception occurred in the DataGridView:

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Property accessor.... 
threw the following exception: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.....*

Made sure that an instance is always created in the constructor of the container object, but that doesn't fix the problem. Any suggestions? This is on Net 2.0

p.s. the data is displayed by the grid, just this error keeps popping up saying the reference is not set to an instance, even though it obviously is. This must be a winforms problem.

**UPDATE**: changing ChimpDiet from a class to a struct removes the errors.
But I need it to be a class. This makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out DataGridView wants the contained object to have a default constructor (no arguments) which initializes every single one of its field data. I don't know why exactly (if someone could shed some light on this, please do) but my program is now working, so that's that.

Answer (score 0):

That is because one of your properties is returning property of class `ChimpDiet`. Without initializing it beforehand when `DataGridView` is trying to show value it tires to access `diet.favoritefood` and when `diet` is null it throws exception.